# Mismatched_Redirect_URI error from Uber API on Safari and Firefox, but not Chrome

Tags: ruby, omniauth, uber-api

My ruby on rails web app was playing nicely with Uber's api when I had the developer credentials on Uber set to `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3000/auth/uber/callback`. Now that I've deployed my app to heroku I updated the credentials to be `https://APP-NAME.herokuapp.com`.

The issue is that when I try to authenticate my app on Chrome (desktop) it works perfectly, but on Safari and Firefox I get an error from Uber: "The base redirect URI does not match the requested redirect". What's odd is that I also get this error when I'm using Chrome on my iPhone. Does anybody have an idea on what the issue is or how to go about troubleshooting this? I have no idea where to start.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. When I visited my app on heroku Safari and Firefox were removing the `https` so when I made the authentication request to Uber it did not match my credentials. In the production.rb file I added `config.force_ssl = true` which causes heroku to use `https`, even when people request the url without adding `https`.